# Unable to run C program through cmd

Tags: c, cmd

Hello everyone I'm learning C and am trying to figure out how to run it through the command console cmd.  I have eclipse installed along with Mingw and added these to the path:

C:\MinGW\bin\;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

I wrote this program on notepad++ for a quick test run and save it to C:\test.c and also under a folder C:\Users\Pikachu\Music\C code while I was trying to figure it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey, Buddy!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On the cmd console I typed:

```
c:\>gcc test.c
```

and got the error message:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/id.exe: cannot ope
n output file a.exe: Invalid argument
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I typed:

```
c:\>cd c:\Users\Pikachu\Music\c code
```

and then:

gcc test.c

it just skipped a line as if nothing happened and went back to square one:

```
c:\Users\Pikachu\Music\c code>gcc test.c

c:\Users\Pikachu\Music\c code>
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what's going on and could help me out, I'd be so happy if I could see "Hey, Buddy" from cmd!  Does anyone also know why I get the error message running it from c:\ and nothing when I run it from the Music\c code\test.c folder even though I'm supposedly running the same file test.c?

I've tried searching around and have picked up references on how the computer can't link to the proper dll's however I'm not sure how to implement this to my specific problem.

Oh and curiously enough when I tried to save another file in c:\ I got a message saying that I didn't have permission to do that even though 5 minutes prior I had done just this.  Any insights?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A simple google search would show you that the command is clearly not write, when compiling you should use -o parameter and you should also write the output file.
gcc -o MY_OUTPUT_FILE_WANTED_NAME.exe MY_C_FILE_NAME.c
after compiling, just run it through the cmd by typing your output file name chosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `gcc` on your C source file, all that it will do it generate an executable file. I believe its called `a.exe` by default but  I would recommend naming it with the `-o` option:

```
gcc text.c -o test.exe
```

Once your file is successfully compiled, run the executable to say hello to the worls:

```
c:\Users\Pikachu\Music\c code> .\test.exe
```

---

As for the first error you got, maybe it has to do with gcc not being able to create the output executable on the root `c:` folder. I would recommend doing your coding some folder your user owns instead of on a system folder for this reason.

---

By the way, gcc supports many other options. I highly recommend using `-Wall` to turn on warnings and choosing what version of the C standard to follow (`-std=c99` or `-ansi`, together with the `-pedantic` flag).

Comment: Yes this is it!  I had to do: gcc test.c -o test.exe and then right after I just typed test.exe and pressed enter and it said Hey, Buddy! on the next line thanks so much!

Comment: Where would I implement these options in Eclipse or cmd?  I tried googling gcc -Wall warning but nothing came up.

Comment: Command line options go after the command name. Just like we did with the `-o` option we would do `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic test.c -o text.exe`. See the gcc documentatio for details (try `gcc --help`). BTW, I think your google search failed because it interpreted the `-` as the ignore command. Try useing quotes `"-Wall"` or removing the hyphen

Comment: you don't need `./` in windows, unlike Linux it will find the executable in the current folder first by default. Or if you want you should use ".\" instead because the folder separator in windows is backslash